# Want to update MySQL DB with the values from excel sheet in minimal time

Tags: mysql, excel, jdbc

I have written below code to read cells from excel and then update it to MySQL table. There are more than 2000 records and this code is only updating the last record but not all the records. If I put 'pstm.executeBatch();' inside for loop, then it updates all the records but one by one, which takes about 2 minutes. I want to reduce this time, so added "&rewriteBatchedStatements=true" in URL and put 'pstm.executeBatch();' outside for loop. In console it shows reading of all the records but the database has only the last record updated.

```
package com.company.testdata;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class UpdateDataCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "test";

        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://192.1.2.1/db_bro_mumbai?useSSL=false"+
                "&rewriteBatchedStatements=true";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";


        try {
            PreparedStatement pstm = null;
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, pass);
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("E:\\Work\\TestData.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFRow row;

            for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {

                row = (XSSFRow) sheet.getRow(i);

                int id = (int)row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
                System.out.println(id);
                String firstname = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println(firstname);
                String middlename = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println(middlename);
                String lastname = row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println(lastname);
                int physicalFitness = (int)row.getCell(25).getNumericCellValue();
                System.out.println(physicalFitness);

                String sql = "UPDATE fitness_details as p SET p.physicalFitness = ? "
                            + " WHERE CandidateID_FK1 = ?";

                pstm = (PreparedStatement) myConn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstm.setInt(1, physicalFitness);
                pstm.setInt(2, id);
                pstm.addBatch();

                //Adding below line will update record one by one which is time consuming, so I commented this and added it after for loop.
                //pstm.executeBatch(); 

                System.out.println("Import rows " + i);
            }
            pstm.executeBatch();
            System.out.println("Imported");
            //myConn.commit();
            //pstm.close();
            //myConn.close();
            input.close();

        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServletException(exc);
        }   
   }
}
```

Comment: You are creating the PreparedStatement on each loop. Probably you win some time, when you prepare the statement before the loop. 
Also System.out.println costs some time. If you print the whole information in one System.out.println it must be much quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. The reason for time delay was due to 'AutoCommit' set to 'true' by default. So I set 'myConn.setAutoCommit(false);' before loop and then run the code. It took about 8 seconds to update db for 2000 records which was about 2 minutes earlier. Below is the code for reference -

```
package com.company.testdata;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class UpdateDataCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "test";
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://192.1.2.1/db_bro_mumbai?useSSL=false";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";


        try {
            PreparedStatement pstm = null;
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, pass);
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("E:\\Work\\TestData.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFRow row;
            myConn.setAutoCommit(false);


            /*final int batchSize = 1000;
            int count = 0;*/
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {


                row = (XSSFRow) sheet.getRow(i);

                int id = (int)row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
                System.out.println(id);
                String firstname = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println(firstname);
                String middlename = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println(middlename);
                String lastname = row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println(lastname);
                int physicalFitness = (int)row.getCell(25).getNumericCellValue();
                System.out.println(physicalFitness);

                String sql = "UPDATE fitness_details as p SET p.physicalFitness = ? "
                            + " WHERE CandidateID_FK1 = ?";

                pstm = (PreparedStatement) myConn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstm.setInt(1, physicalFitness);
                pstm.setInt(2, id);
                pstm.addBatch();

                pstm.executeBatch();

                System.out.println("Import rows " + i);
            }
            System.out.println("Time Taken="+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
            myConn.commit();
            myConn.setAutoCommit(true);
            pstm.close();
            myConn.close();
            input.close();

        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServletException(exc);
        }   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Has mentioned in my comment...

```
    package com.company.testdata;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

    public class UpdateDataCopy {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String user = "root";
            String pass = "test";

            String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://172.16.206.197/db_bro_mumbai?useSSL=false"+
            "&rewriteBatchedStatements=true";
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";


            try {
                PreparedStatement pstm = null;
                Class.forName(driver);
                Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, pass);
                String sql = "UPDATE fitness_details as p SET p.physicalFitness = ?  WHERE CandidateID_FK1 = ?";

                pstm = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

                FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("E:\\Work\\TestData.xlsx");
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                XSSFRow row;

                for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {

                    row = (XSSFRow) sheet.getRow(i);

                    int id = (int)row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
                    String firstname = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
                    String middlename = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
                    String lastname = row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
                    int physicalFitness = (int)row.getCell(25).getNumericCellValue();
                    pstm.setInt(1, physicalFitness);
                    pstm.setInt(2, id);
                    pstm.addBatch();

                    System.out.println("Import rows " + I + "ID: " +  id + " Middlename:" + middlename + " Lastname:" + lastname + "  Physicalfitness:" + physicalFitness );
                }
                pstm.executeBatch();
                System.out.println("Imported");
                //myConn.commit();
                pstm.close();
                myConn.close();
                input.close();

            }
            catch (Exception exc) {
               exc.printStackTrace();
                throw new ServletException(exc);
            }   
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is taking almost same time as before.